# How to get the line number of error in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to get the line number of an error when running a PowerShell script. Here is what I'm using at the moment:

```
$e = $_.Exception
$line = $_.Exception.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber
$msg = $e.Message 

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "caught exception: $e at $line"
```

Sometimes this works and sometimes it doesn't. I'm wondering if I'm doing anything wrong, or what I can do to make this work more consistently.

Comment: Are try catch statements not giving you the information you need? Is this in a catch?

Comment: No the try/catch only gives the error. It doesn't list the line number and stuff.

Comment: I guessed (Although no exceptions to catch now) that something like: catch {[Exception] $_.ScriptLineNumber } might do it... But I also just catch my errors and echo the exception and it generally gives me what I need. So I am glad you found it.

Comment: I was wrong, I am using a try/catch. This code is in the catch statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get detailed exception stacktrace in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795751/can-i-get-detailed-exception-stacktrace-in-powershell)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was:

Instead of:

```
$e = $_.Exception
#this is wrong
$line = $_.Exception.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber
$msg = $e.Message 

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "caught exception: $e at $line"
```

### It should be

```
$e = $_.Exception
$line = $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber
$msg = $e.Message 

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "caught exception: $e at $line"
```

Comment: I think Abu's answer is preferable, or even just `Write-Error $_.Exception.Message`

Answer (score 12):

here's another useful way to capture a detailed exception

```bsh
try
{
    throw "fdsfds"
}
catch
{
    Write-Error ($_.Exception | Format-List -Force | Out-String) -ErrorAction Continue
    Write-Error ($_.InvocationInfo | Format-List -Force | Out-String) -ErrorAction Continue
    throw
}
```