# How to display line numbers where Powershell exceptions are raised

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

My Powershell script is throwing an exception, but not giving me the line number where the exception is thrown:

```
The process cannot access the file 'C:/path/to/foo.txt' because it is being used by another process.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-Content], IOException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand
+ PSComputerName        : localhost
```

I would think the best practice here is to refactor the script to use try/catch blocks to narrow down exactly where the `Set-Content` exception is being thrown - but in this case, due to the size/scope of the script, I am trying to avoid that option.

Instead, I'm hoping for a bit of a top-down solution - for instance, being able to call the script with added verbosity, in such a way that Powershell prints the line numbers in the stack traces (pretty sure Python does this by default).

Does Powershell 3.0 natively support this?

**EDIT**: The accepted answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226718/how-to-get-the-line-number-of-error-in-powershell) involves the try/catch approach, which I have mentioned is not my preferred approach.  Again, is there some way to get PowerShell to report line numbers when exceptions are raised without mandatory try/catches?  Would I have to wrap the entire script in a generic try/catch?  Would I have to invoke the script with some `--verbose` flag?  Does Powershell 3.0 support anything like that?

Comment: Could you add the script causing the error?

Comment: There should be `At D:\PShell\SO\56588150.ps1:21 char:1` line  (or alike). You can check the property `$Error[0].ScriptStackTrace`.

Comment: Alternatively, `$Error[0].InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the line number of error in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226718/how-to-get-the-line-number-of-error-in-powershell)

Comment: @Moerwald This was not a duplicate of that question - the accepted answer involves the try/catch block approach (`$_.Exception` is called in the context of a catch block).

Comment: @JosefZ Nope - I included the full exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Set-PsDebug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-psdebug?view=powershell-6) is going to print every command one the console, while a script is running.

```
Set-PSDebug -Trace 2; foreach ($i in 1..3) {$i}
```

> ```
> DEBUG:    1+ Set-PsDebug -Trace 2; foreach ($i in 1..3) {$i}
> DEBUG:    1+ Set-PsDebug -Trace 2; foreach ($i in 1..3) {$i}
> 1
> DEBUG:    1+ Set-PsDebug -Trace 2; foreach ($i in 1..3) {$i}
> 2
> DEBUG:    1+ Set-PsDebug -Trace 2; foreach ($i in 1..3) {$i}
> 3
> ```

Comment: Thanks Moerwald - this is exactly the kind of thing what I'm looking for.  For the sake of those would find [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-psdebug?view=powershell-3.0) bewildering - to use this, you would just throw `Set-PSDebug -Trace 1` somewhere in the context of the script itself.  This will show every line executed, along with a message like `DEBUG: 1739+` - very ugly but it works.