# powershell Command Works When run alone, but note when scripted

Tags: powershell

I am working on a deployment script for some software, and my script is working on probably 90% of the machines it runs on, but on the other 10%, I get a failure in the download portion.  Here is what I have:

```
$tls = "Tls";
$Token = "@ZorusKey@";
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $tls;
$source = <Source>
$destination = "C:\installers\ZorusInstaller.exe";
$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.DownloadFile($source, $destination)
```

I have created the C:\installers folder on all target machines, so I don't think that's the problem.  When run as a script, I get the following exception:

Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
At C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\f1e96243cb9c4ef0b0336a152ed8827f.ps1:8 char:1
+ $WebClient.DownloadFile($source, $destination)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

Which then causes the following steps to fail, as the downloaded file doesn't exist.

I have also taken the step on several of the failing machines of running each line of the script above one at a time (copied / pasted from the same Powershell ISE window) and the download works without issue.  looking for a possible reason / resolution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could this be a user permissions thing perhaps? Not everyone is allowed to access the C:\ drive. Is your deployment script working under admin credentials?

Comment: Yes.  Deployment is happening through RMM Software, and this script is part of a larger script. It gets the defined admin credentials for the machine from the database and verifies they are actually valid, if that fails the script exits immediately.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Based upon the error message, it looks as if the script is running in the local SYSTEM context, is that correct?  If so, does your remote resource require domain-level authentication perhaps?  If so, using local SYSTEM will probably not work.  Otherwise, see if [grabbing the inner exception message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22894323/11609403) reveals any further insights.  Good luck.

Comment: I found the issue.  I was executing this powershell script as a local admin (the larger RMM Script verified Admin credentials prior to this), but running it as local system (download is coming from Amazon AWS) removed the UAC prompt