# Referring to current object from different scope

Tags: powershell, scoping

I want to be able to refer to `$_` object in catch block from the function I call in catch block like this:

```
function foo
{
    $something = ((Get-Variable -Name "_" -Scope 1).Value).Exception.Message
    Write-Host $something
}
```

I want to use this in situations like these:

```
foo #write-host should print empty line
try {
    throw
} catch {
    foo #write-host should print $_.Exception.Message from this catch block
}
```

How to do that properly?
The goal is to avoid passing `$_` as parameter to `foo` every time I use it in a catch block, and not to print anything when I call `foo` not in a catch block.

I have also tried this:

```
function foo
{
    $something = (($ExecutionContext.SessionState.PSVariable.Get("_")).Value).Exception.Message
    Write-Host $something
}
```

This seems to produce the result I want when working interactively, but not when launching script.

Comment: There's a global `$error` variable. `$error[0]` holds the last error encountered.

Comment: the fact that it is global produces unwanted results when calling "foo" not in a catch block, in that case I don't want it to return the last error it has saved from previous catch block.

Comment: Frankly, I would give `foo()` a parameter with a default value of `$null` and call `foo $_` in a catch block. Output the exception message only if the argument is of type `[Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]`.

Comment: This is what we are doing currently, I'm exploring what can be done to avoid that. At least intuitively I would expect that this can be avoided, since we are always passing the same argument.

Comment: Like `$error`, no solution with `Get-Variable` is globally stable either, since `Foo` could always be called with a `$_` variable in scope that has nothing to do with a `catch` block, even if your approach worked. (This is true no matter what you call `_`.) There's a reason parameters are part of the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *clean* way of doing this is, of course, an (optional) parameter on `foo`, called with `foo $_` from `catch` blocks. This makes it perfectly clear what we're calling `foo` with, it has no issues with scoping, it makes `foo` testable, all that niceness. You will see this approach in most anything that prints errors (as in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795751), for example).

Even so, if you *insist* on plucking the error variable from the parent frame, it can be done:

```
function foo {
    $lastError = (Get-PSCallStack)[1].GetFrameVariables()["_"].Value
    if ([Object]::ReferenceEquals($lastError.Exception, $error[0].Exception)) {
        $lastError.Exception.Message
    }
}
```

Note the extra trickery with `Object.ReferenceEquals` to be absolutely sure that `$_` is referring to the last error record and not some arbitrary pipeline item (which also use `$_`). This will *still* fail if the error record itself is in the pipeline (e.g. `$error |% { foo }`), but at that point you might as well call it a feature.