# How can I force powershell to output all errors normally in cmd?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I want to be able to use Sysnative cmd to execute a powershell script and output the results to a log.

When I run (System32):

`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C "powershell -file “C:\…\ScriptWithErrors.ps1" >> C:\…\Log.log”`

My log will show the errors from the powershell file (that usually show up in red in a terminal)

However when I run (Sysnative):

`C:\Windows\Sysnative\cmd.exe /C "powershell -file “C:\…\ScriptWithErrors.ps1" >> C:\…\Log.log”`

My log will not show any errors from the powershell script that I don’t explicitly use `Write-Host $_.Exception` for.

Is there a way to execute a powershell script and force the output of the errors to output?

Also, why does using `cmd \C` make echo not work properly?

```
>> C:\Windows\Sysnative\cmd.exe /C "echo time \t”
>> time /t (Output)
>> 11:20 AM (Expected output)
```

Comment: Why are you using non matching smart and double quotes? And why are you sending the powershell command output to a file and not the cmd.exe output?

Comment: What would be an example of matching smart and double quotes? And because I want to save the output in a log.

Comment: @Compo Also, redirecting the output from cmd.exe to a log doesn't work.

Comment: There shouldn't be any smart quotes, look at your code again, they use both **`“`** and **`"`**. You could use single quotes around your `.ps1` file name too: `…\cmd.exe /C "powershell -file 'C:\…\ScriptWithErrors.ps1'">>"C:\…\Log.log"`.

Comment: Have you tried launching powershell directly instead of proxying it through a command prompt? `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` or `%SystemRoot%\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` or maybe via `sysnative` in your case.

Comment: "*Also, why does using cmd \C make echo not work properly?*" - your output is exactly what I'd expect. Your expected output is not. Why would "echo" run commands instead of echoing text? `cmd /c "time /t"` should be the output you expect

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Launching a cmd and running "echo time /t" gives me the time. That's why it is the expected output.

Comment: @user1222324562 -> https://i.imgur.com/ShrQNqB.png -> it doesn't give me that? What OS version are you using?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powershell will save ALL errors for a session in the $Error variable.
The newest error will be number 0 in the array.

So basically to get all errors for a session you could just end up exporting the entire $Error variable array to your log, or foreach through it and get the parts you are interested in.

To get the line number of the error you could use the property ScriptStackTrace on the error variable.

For example I run:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\cmder
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\nodirhere
```

The first line gives me the output, the second an error.
Now checking the newest error in the $Error array by selecting position 0 in the array and asking for the scriptstacktrace I get:

```
$Error[0].ScriptStackTrace
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 2
```

Comment: There is a property on the error variable called ScriptStackTrace.
I will update the answer with some info.

Comment: Check out script here to resolve the error record object and log the details you are interested in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795751/can-i-get-detailed-exception-stacktrace-in-powershell/24644666#24644666