# Why does TeamCity's PowerShell Build Runner display a stack trace instead of error output?

Tags: powershell, teamcity

I am using TeamCity's out-of-the-box PowerShell  Build Runner to run script provided in the Build Step. The script is effectively:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

$match = select-string "%EwlProjectPackagesConfigPath%" -pattern "<package id=`"(Ewl)`" version=`"([0-9\.pr-]+)`".+/>"
$ewlPackage = $match.Matches.Captures.Groups[1]
$version = $match.Matches.Captures.Groups[2]

$devUtil = Get-ChildItem "%PackagesDirectory%\$ewlPackage.$version\Development Utility\EnterpriseWebLibrary.DevelopmentUtility.exe"
& $devUtil "%SolutionDirectory%" UpdateAllDependentLogic
if ($LastExitCode -ne 0) {
    Throw "Process exit code: $LastExitCode";
```

The exe being called by the `&` operator is running into a problem. It outputs to Standard Error and returns code 1. Here is a screenshot of the output in TeamCity:

[image: Screenshot of TeamCity build output where it shows a PowerShell stack trace instead of the full error output]

The output in TeamCity is only showing exactly one line of error output (6/26/2019 2:48:55 PM:  Failed to update database logic.), and then a stack trace of the problem in the script.

I'm unable to reproduce this outside of TeamCity. If I save the script to my desktop and run the following command, which should be the same as what is being executed by TeamCity:

> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile
>   -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Test.ps1"

Then I receive about a hundred lines of error output (which I would like to be seeing in TeamCity), and I do not see a stack trace at all.

1. Why doesn't TeamCity capture the entire error output?
2. How does TeamCity display a stack trace and why do I not when I run the script in the same manner?

Comment: that's question not to teamcity, but to powershell. powershell does not print stacktrace to stderr or stdout that's why teamcity can't catch any additional info for you. there are alot of questions  how to catch and print stacktrace in powershell.

Comment: I'm not sure how it's not a question to TeamCity if it's the one doing the special behavior that you're saying PowerShell does not do by default.

Comment: look, there is a similar question about powershell (without teamcity): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795751/can-i-get-detailed-exception-stacktrace-in-powershell

Comment: But your point and link both show that it's not automatic, and not even trivial, to get a PowerShell stacktrace. And in my situation, I'm getting one, don't want one, and don't understand why it's being shown instead of the output being sent before the error even occurs.

Comment: sorry, maybe i didn't understand your question then.