# Having issue returning full error information

Tags: powershell

I am catching exceptions and want to return the full content and did some tests and it worked but now it isn't working and can't figure out why or if it's intermittent.

```
Try {
        Get-Secret -Vault $vaultName -Name $secretId -AsPlainText -EA Stop
    } 
    Catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException] {
        # Next line outputs the error message string, as expected
        Write-Output ("error:" + $_)
        # Only outputs standard error message block, but worked during initial testing
        Write-Error $_ | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5
        #Next line just like previous
        #Write-Error $_.Exception | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You want the trace stack (inner errors).  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795751/can-i-get-detailed-exception-stacktrace-in-powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending the caught error (`$_`) to the [Error Stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams?view=powershell-7.3#error-stream) when using [`Write-Error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-error?view=powershell-7.3) and `ConvertTo-Json` can only capture output sent to the [Success Stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams?view=powershell-7.3#success-stream).

You have 2 options, if you want to serialize the error record and **not send it to the Error Stream** just remove `Write-Error`:

```bash
Try {
    throw 'foo'
}
Catch {
    $_ | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5
}
```

If you want to serialize the error record **and send it to the Error Stream**, then `Write-Error` should be the last in your pipeline:

```bash
Try {
    throw 'foo'
}
Catch {
    $_ | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5 | Write-Error
}
```

Comment: It makes so much sense, shows that I'm new to PS